# update product created_at date via php

Tags: magento-1.7, product, php

I'm trying to figure out how can I change the `created_at` date of a product.

can somebody point me in the right direction on how to do it?

I can't even find where it's stored in the database.

Answer (score 3):

Usually this would be handled automatically by Magento it self.

The structure of the data is a MySQL DateTime format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` and is stored within the `catalog_product_entity` (although other tables will store this information for individual elements of data as well)

You should be able to update it by using the Magento model.

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1); 
$model->setCreatedAt('2015-01-01 09:00:00'); 
$model->save();
```

Note however that you may require to be within the admin context as front end product model may not allow saving of the product for security reasons.

Comment: Thank you John Cuthbert. That actually helped me a lot!! I wrote a similar script but it wasn't working... that's because I didn't call Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID); thank you for pointing that out!!! and thank you for the help p.s. I can't comment nor accept your answer, I don't know why